# Why Python-Eve does not overwrites Flask JSON encoder

Tags: python, flask, eve

When initializing Eve one can specify a custom made json encoder, like it is specified in the documentation [here](http://docs.python-eve.org/en/latest/tutorials/custom_idfields.html#custom-jsonencoder), you can make something like:

```
from eve.io.base import BaseJSONEncoder
    class CustomJSONEncoder(BaseJSONEncoder):
        ...   
app = Eve(settings=settings, json_encoder=CustomJSONEncoder)
```

What I expected is that, internally, the result would be:

```
flask.json_encoder == CustomJSONEncoder
```

but what I found in the [flaskapp Eve code](https://github.com/pyeve/eve/blob/master/eve/flaskapp.py#L170) is that:

```
self.data.json_encoder_class = CustomJSONEncoder
```

which is accessible later on with `app.data.json_encoder_class`. This causes that if you use any flask add-on which relies on the encoder, you will not have the custom encodings you expect.

The straighforward solution may be:

```
app = Eve(settings=settings, json_encoder=CustomJSONEncoder)
app.json_encoder = CustomJSONEncoder
```

but I wonder:

- Why Eve does not do it itself?
- Is there any reason to avoid changing Flask's default JSON encoder?
- Does Eve makes something 'extra the `data.json_encoder_class`?
- Should this be documented?